# Openshift - Variables in Config for different Environments

Tags: yaml, openshift, environment

I am currently trying to make deployments on two different openshift clusters, but I only want to use one deploymentconfig file. Is there a good way to overcome the current problem

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: DeploymentConfig
metadata:
  labels:
    app: my-app
    deploymentconfig: my-app
  name: my-app
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-app
    deploymentconfig: my-app
  strategy:
    type: Rolling
    rollingParams:
      intervalSeconds: 1
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailability: 25%
      timeoutSeconds: 600
      updatePeriodSeconds: 1
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
        deploymentconfig: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-app-container
          image: 172.0.0.1:5000/int-myproject/my-app:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: ROUTE_PATH
              value: /my-app
            - name: HTTP_PORT
              value: "8080"
            - name: HTTPS_PORT
              value: "8081"
    restartPolicy: Always
    dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
```

Now if you look at spec.template.spec.containers[0].image there are two problems with this

**Nr.1**

**172.0.0.1:5000**/int-myproject/my-app:latest

The IP of the internal registry will differ between the two environments

**Nr.2**

172.0.0.1:5000/**int-myproject**/my-app:latest

The namespace will also not be the same. In this scenario I want this to be int-myproject or prod-myproject depending on the environment i want to deploy to. I was thinking maybe there is a way to use parameters in the yaml and pass them to openshift somehow similar to this

```
oc create -f deploymentconfig.yaml --namespace=int-myproject
```

and have a parameter like ${namespace} in my yaml file. Is there a good way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, to answer your question, yes you can use parameters with OpenShift templates and pass the value and creation time.

To do this, you will [add the required template values](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/templates.html#writing-parameters) to your yaml file and  instead of using `oc create` you will use `oc new-app -f deploymentconfig.yaml --param=SOME_KEY=someValue`. Check out `oc new-app --help` for more info here.

Some other points to note though: IF you are referencing images from internal registry you might be better off to use [imagestreams](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/core_concepts/builds_and_image_streams.html#image-streams). These provide an abstraction for images pulled from internal docker registry on OpenShift, as is the case you have outlined.

Finally, the namespace value is [available via the downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/#capabilities-of-the-downward-api) in every Pod and you should not need to (typically) inject that manually.

Comment: thanks. I actually am using with imagestreams and pushing my build into an is. I guess i referenced it wrong in my deploymentconfig then. Do I need to reference the IS under triggers as described in the link and remove the image completely from the container spec or do i need to reference it there?

Comment: You will still reference the image in the container spec but it will not be the ip it would be the image stream name which should allow you to make it generic across clusters. Try deploy any service from the catalog, nodejs for example and take a look at the objects it produces (builds, imagestreams, deployment) as a guide

Comment: thats what i tried at first so i just have Image: my-app:latest but that will always give me an error (ImagePullBackOff) on pulling the image with "rpc error: code = 2 desc = unauthorized:authentication required

Comment: What version of OpenShift are you running and in what environment/os?

Comment: Oh and maybe one last question. I was unable to google it. If I use templates, is it possible to reference the objects from files? I would prefer it a little more modular than writing verything in one long file

Comment: Running 3.9.0 on RedHat

Comment: " is it possible to reference the objects from files? " do you mean compose a template from different files? If so, not with the standard tooling. You could look at using something like helm for this if required.

Comment: yes that was exaclty what i meant. thanks for the help. I will take a look at it.